# Redshift query executed through python gives no records

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I've written the following query to be executed through Python.

```
query="""SELECT DISTINCT count(*) FROM PG_TABLE_DEF WHERE schemaname='master'  AND tablename LIKE '%%tmp%%'; """
#print(query)

conn=func_redshiftconnection()
res=conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text(query))
res=res.fetchall()
print(res)                # Prints (0,)
```

It works fine in the database but is giving me 0 results when I execute it through Python and SqlAlchemy with `psycopg2`.

Idon't understand what the problem could be. Thanks for reading

Comment: It might be some characters that need escaping. Can you try a simpler query, such as `SELECT 42` and see whether it works? If so, it's just a matter of debugging your particular query.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein `SELECT 42` does work

Comment: Great, now just keep working up to your full query. For example, try `SELECT COUNT(*) from PG_TABLE_DEF`, then add bits at a time until it breaks. My guess is that it would probably be your percentage symbols, but that's for you to test.

Comment: In the `where` clause, schemaname='public' gets me results. But not when the schema name is 'master'. I don't understand why.

Comment: Does it work if you access the database directly? Are you using the same credentials for both connections? You might have to [wrap your request in a try/catch](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial) to see the error.

Comment: There is no error. And yes I am using the same credentials. The count is 0 and no results are coming. I know this could be a simple mistake but it's really confusing right now

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Is that possible

Comment: When I look at `PG_TABLE_DEF` in an Amazon Redshift cluster, I can only see a schemaname of `pg_catalog`. So, the other schemas must be created by your system. Also, please note that your `DISTINCT` is not actually doing anything because it is returning a DISTINCT of your single count, which is itself -- but that shouldn't be causing your problem. If you are getting different results between an SQL client and `psycopg2`, it would suggest you are using different credentials. Beyond that, I cannot assist further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PG_TABLE_DEF in Redshift only returns information about tables that are visible to the user, in other words, it will only show you the tables which are in the schema(s) which are defined in variable search_path. If PG_TABLE_DEF does not return the expected results, verify that the search_path parameter is set correctly to include the relevant schema(s).
Source - [PG_TABLE_DEF](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html)

Try this -

```
mydb=# set search_path="$user",master;
```

Then run your query -

```
mydb=# select tablename from pg_table_def where schemaname = 'master';
```

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and get back to you

Comment: Thank you so much @Rahul. This worked. And also I realized it only runs for the set session. This worked like a charm! Thanks again :)